# Creating a list instance from the STP template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So let's say I've got a STP template deployed to the gallery. Is there any way I could deploy a list instance from a XML file based on this template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is to create a list dynamically  with the same stp installed in the gallery right? pelase correct me if I misunderstood your question

if this is the case then you can creat a custom solution in which you should have this stp as a module and deploymnet of solution you can add this stp into the list templated gallery and create a list fromn this stp from the code programtically

Refer this link

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Upload-Custom-list-template-and-create-List-Instance-from-custom-list-template-Using-PowerShell-in-SharePoint-2013